# Scoping current accounts in the url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

How does Basecamp set up their routes to be scoped to a current account?

```
basecamp.com/12345/
```

The `12345` is an account number. How can I setup my routes to achieve the same effect?

I don't want to pass the account number to all my routes.

```
new_account_post_comments_path(@account, @post)
# /account/12345/posts/12345
```

I want to do this:

```
new_post_comments_path(@post)
# /12345/posts/12345
```

In other words, I don't want to have to pass an account object to all my urls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing the current account_id is probably stored in a session, and the route looks something similar to this:

```
  scope "/:account_id", account_id: lambda{|request| request.session[:account_id]} do
    resources :posts
  end
```

Comment: how would you use urls like `/foo` that do not belong to the account id scope then?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. You can always define routes outside the scope block.

Comment: yes, but if I define something like `get '/foo', to 'foos#foo'` wouldn't it try and find an account with `account_id = foo`. I mean, how would it know `.com/foo` is not `.com/:account_id` ?

Comment: If you define ```get '/foo', to: 'foos#foo'``` BEFORE the scope block, it'll match that first.

Comment: OK. I understand, in other words, I have to make sure that this is the next thing about the root path. Thanks.

Comment: hmm.. it seems very "dirty" storing the account id in the session. Can you think of another place I could store it?

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with storing the current account id in a session for scoping purposes. There's one catch though: you should always make sure the user has access to that account on page load. I'd suggest you create a helper method `current_account` which does something like this: `current_user.accounts.find(session[:account_id])`